# Lists as least fixed point of a functor

Tags: haskell, recursive-datastructures

I thought I understood Haskell's lists, until I stumbled recently on recursive infinite lists, such as

```
let idList = 0 : (map (+1) idList)
```

which is the infinite list of numbers 0, 1, 2, ...

Now I wonder what is the mathematical definition of Haskell's recursive data types like lists and trees. This article about [F-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-algebra) mentions "Types defined by using least fixed point construct with functor F can be regarded as an initial F-algebra, provided that parametricity holds for the type.".

Is this where Haskell's types come from ?

Comment: You may be interested in the following:
https://gist.github.com/jdegoes/97459c0045f373f4eaf126998d8f65dc#data--codata
https://gist.github.com/jdegoes/97459c0045f373f4eaf126998d8f65dc#recursion-schemes

Comment: In this case, `idList` is simply taking advantage of lazy evaluation; F-algebras are not involved.

Comment: @chepner `idList` is just an example. My question is about the recursive type `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`. What is its mathematical foundation ?

Comment: [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F)

Comment: Again, I think it's just laziness. https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/bartosz/understanding-algebras has an interesting comment at the very end, to the effect that the compiler [presumably, GHC] optimizes recursive code poorly, so writing explicitly non-recursive code has performance benefits.

Comment: A possibly-infinite list `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)` (or definitely infinite `data List a = Cons a (List a)`) is codata (greatest fixed point), while a finite list `data List a = Nil | Cons a !(List a)` is data (least fixed point).

Comment: @JonPurdy ...and greatest and least fixed points coincide in Haskell due to laziness, right? (Can't remember where I read that...)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, I believe Jon Purdy's code example shows both lazy and eager (strict) definitions of lists, in other words greatest and least fixed point versions.